# Round up final output in jquery

Tags: jquery, math, rounding

I have the following code. Works beautifully apart from i want the final tinstotal variable to be rounded up to the nearest 1 (2.04 being rounded up to 3 etc)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Animate logo
$('#Logo').hide().fadeIn(800);

// Calculation Scripts
// Square Metres
var output = $('#SquareMetres'),
    tinoutput = $('#Tins'),
    priceoutput = $('#Price');
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
var width = parseFloat( $('#width').val()),
    height = parseFloat( $('#height').val()),
    result = height * width / 10000,
    finalresult = result.toFixed(2);
if (isNaN(result)) return;

output.text(finalresult);

// Tins
var tinmetres = 32.5,
    tinprice = 18.23,
    tinsresult = finalresult / tinmetres;
    tinstotal = tinsresult.toFixed(2);

tinoutput.text(tinstotal);

var price = tinstotal * tinprice,
    totalprice = price.toFixed(2);

priceoutput.text('£'+totalprice)

});
});
```

the script is active here at http://andyholmes.me/sitewizard/index.html in the red box near the bottom. Hope you guys can help, thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
tinstotal = Math.ceil(tinsresult);
tinoutput.text(tinstotal);
```

[Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) will round to the next whole number

Comment: You are already using Math.Ceil() So there is not point of using .toFixed(2)

Answer (score 5):

use javascript Math.round()

```
ex: 
var a = Math.round(2.60);
var b = Math.round(-2.60);
var c = Math.round(2.49);

Result : 
alert(a); => 3
alert(b); => -3
alert(c); => 2
```

Hope is helps you.

Comment: This does not round up as requested. Your example clearly shows it rounds to nearest int.

Answer (score 1):

```
priceoutput.text('£'+ Math.ceil(totalprice));
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Answer (score 1):

use javascript's Math.ceil() method to round numbers up.

you can view information about this method here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you are looking for [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```
Math.ceil(7.004);
// expected output: 8

Math.ceil(-7.004);
// expected output: -7
```